# Generating 1-18 simple worldmap with mapnik

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, mapnik, cyprus

I have PostgreSQL with PostGIS and mapnik, I need to generate a tiled world map with only country contours and country name that are displayed at all zoom levels, no extra info.

How can I do it without using osm2pgsql importing all the planet.osm (20gb)?

I generate a map using for example cyprus.osm but the area of Cyprus is now of course filled with additional information not required that slow down the generation process.

If i start the generate_tiles.py utility without use osm2pgsql I get many errors.. there is nothing like a void osm-file?

How can I configure the map style to display only country contours and name, at all zoom levels?

Comment: How did you get on with this?  I'm facing the same issue -- I want to generate really simple map tiles, but I cannot load the 21GB planet.osm.bz2 file into Maperitive on my machine without it grinding to a halt.  I'm now looking at using pgsql.  I'd be interested in hearing how you got on with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Administrative Boundaries from here http://downloads.cloudmade.com/

example:

switzerland.administrative.osm.bz2 (9.4M) shapefile.

Contours from

http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/

(same source as http://www.toposm.com/us/index.html)